# HttpsParameters cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, ssl, https

I want to secure my http request ,Im using something like http://123.456.789.123:1234 and I want secure it. I create a keystore.csr carets.jks server.cer and keystore.jks with the java keytool after that I implement my code, but it can't read HttpsParameters

```
String alias = "alias";
char [] storepass = "changeit".toCharArray();
String keystoreName = "c:\\keystore.jks";
FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(keystoreName);
KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
keystore.load(in, storepass);
Certificate cert = keystore.getCertificate(alias);
Log.debug("the certification is here : " + cert);
KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
char [] keypass = "changeit".toCharArray();
kmf.init(keystore, keypass);
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
tmf.init(keystore);
HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(port), 0);
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
server.setHttpsConfigurator(new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext) {
  public void configure(HttpsParameters params) {
    try {
       SSLContext c = SSLContext.getDefault();
       SSLEngine engine = c.createSSLEngine();
       params.setNeedClientAuth(false);
       params.setCipherSuites(engine.getEnabledCipherSuites());
       params.setProtocols(engine.getEnabledProtocols());
       SSLParameters defaultSSLParameters=c.getDefaultSSLParameters();
       params.setSSLParameters(defaultSSLParameters);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to create HTTPS server");
                  }
                   }
               });`
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of what exactly are you trying to do and what results do you get back? Do you get any exceptions?

Comment: if I delete the method configure(HttpsParameters params) cause like I said HttpsParameters  cannot be resolved to a type ,I got a 404 Not FOUND no context found for request

Comment: "...cause like I said HttpsParameters cannot be resolved to a type.." I have no idea what you mean by this.

Comment: I have a red line under HttpsParameters and the problem is "cannot be resolved to a type" I really don't know why cause all the examples that I saw are using HttpsParameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a mistake that I forgot to add the import to my class

```
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpsParameters;
```